# Showing a blank UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am populating a UITableView with the following code in swift. Unfortunately it is show a blank tableview not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController
{

    var cities: [City]?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let london = City(name: "London", coordinates: (51.50722, -0.12750))
        let melbourne = City(name: "Melbourne", coordinates: (-37.8136, 144.9631))
        let singapore = City(name: "Singapore", coordinates: (-23.5475000,-46.6361100))
        let saopaulo = City(name: "Sao Paulo", coordinates: (49.3297,8.57428))
        let nurbergring = City(name: "Nurbergring", coordinates: (45.58005,9.27246))
        cities?.append(london)
        cities?.append(melbourne)
        cities?.append(singapore)
        cities?.append(saopaulo)
        cities?.append(nurbergring)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
```

Comment: this is what I have `override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cities?.count ?? 0
    }
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
             let city = cities?[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = city!.name
        return cell
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cities: [City]?
```

This line means that you declare `cities` as optional array, that is, it can be `nil` value. Because `cities` is only declared and not initialized at this point, its value is `nil`.

After that, in `viewDidLoad`, you create an `City` object and try to add it to `cities` array, but it will not be added, because `cities` has a `nil` value. You need initialize it first:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    cities = [] // initialize as an empty array
    let london = City(name: "London", coordinates: (51.50722, -0.12750))
    // ...
    cities?.append(london)
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UITableView delegate methods. Here's what you should do :

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cities.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("reuseIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel.text= cities[indexPath.row].name //Or add others here
    return cell
}
```

[Here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/uitableview) are some tutorials you should check out, which will brush up your iOS skills. And also note that the first method is optional, but it's a good practice to implement it.

Comment: I have done that. I was not able to show that code as post said I exceeded my code allowance.

Comment: Hmm, so have you surely linked your TableView? And also make sure you set `tableView.delegate=self` and `tableView.dataSource=self`,

Comment: I am not using the delegate method.

Comment: Then what are you using? Please remove the code you have added above and add the legit one.

Comment: Sorry the TableView is linked to a delegate as outlets in the storyboard.

Comment: It should work then, just add <code>tableView.dataSource=self</code>

Comment: I am a newbie to this. So where would I add this `tableView.delegate=self and tableView.dataSource=self`

Comment: Add it to viewDidLoad. And also, iI think you should replace cities?.count ?? 0 to only cities?.count.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the cell reuse identifier is correctly named on the storyboard?

Comment: Yes. It does say Cell.

Comment: @Carlos Please do not edit non-answers.  As you can see, this post is not an answer (it is a request for clarification and should be a comment), and should be deleted.  Editing non-answers invalidates community flags on them.